# What type of car has the brightest headlights?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Stack Exchange post: [What type of car has the brightest headlights?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/60660/what-type-of-car-has-the-brightest-headlights)

Can this please be reopened? I changed the post to focus on the car, and not rentals.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Probably this will be closed as well but before it does off-roaders usually fit their car very strong lights due to obvious lack of daylight. That might be a little dangerous for other drivers and might be illegal in your country but you can fit something like that and use them manually as high beams. Also, you can upgrade any car's lights by replacing them with LEDs. Replace dimming out headlight glasses if the car is old.

Comment: This *really* doesn't answer the question at large. Realize, the Meta side of the site is to ask questions about the site and how it's run, not to answer questions about Mechanics. The original question was closed due to it being off-topic for the site, as deemed by the members of the site (not by us mods). To me, when the users of the site speak, I tend to leave their decisions alone.